# ValueError: Array contains NaN or infinity while using scikit learn recursive feature elimination with cross val

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using scikit module recursive feature elimination with cross val(RFECV) for feature selection. 
The code snippet is as follows:

```
svc = SVC(kernel="linear")

rfecv = RFECV(estimator=svc, step=20, cv=StratifiedKFold(y, 2),scoring='roc_auc')

rfecv.fit(X,y)
```

I get an error `ValueError: Array contains NaN or infinity` when I run my code in sklearn/utils/validation.py.

The following check in validation.py

```
X.dtype.char in np.typecodes['AllFloat'] and not np.isfinite(X.sum()) and not np.isfinite(X).all()
```

returns False when I test it on X. X is not sparse.So ideally I should not get this error.

Please can someone let me know what may be the cause of the error.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you scale your features using `preprocessing.StandardScaler`? You should, before feeding them to an SVM. Not doing so can cause this error (as well as very slow training).

Comment: If X is sparse it shouldn't be possible to use the StandardScaler but just scale, right?

Comment: Please always report the complete traceback otherwise there is no way to be sure where this happens.

Comment: If the data is sparse, just ensure that the distribution of the values are not too heavy tailed. If there are and are all positive, then taking `np.log(1 + X)` or `np.sqrt(X)` might help SVM behave better.